# JQuery inccorectly append created JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

folks.

I have question about Jquery.append() method. I nothing found in documentation about my problem (or I doesn't search enough).

I have following HTML markup.

```
<li class="active bug-droppable" bugId="1">
  <a href="#">Super Bug 1 
    <span class="badge badge-primary">2</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I using bootstrap and want to add span tag which represent icon to anchor tag.

I do following and this works good enough. But I want to create function which allow customize icon. ("this" references to "li")

```
var PLUS_ICON = '<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign medium-icon"></span>';
$(this).find("a").append(PLUS_ICON);
```

I tried following, it's looks similar but it doesn't work.

```
var ICON_DUMMY = '<span class="glyphicon medium-icon"></span>'
var ICON_PLUS_CLASS = ".glyphicon-plus-sign";
var PULL_RIGHT = ".pull-right";

var $icon = $(ICON_DUMMY).addClass(ICON_PLUS_CLASS).addClass(PULL_RIGHT);
$(this).find("a").append($icon);
```

Who can explain why second case doesn't work?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Omit the `.` inside `addClass()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a period in front of the class name.  That is invalid for class attribute.
Change like so and it should work.

```
var ICON_PLUS_CLASS = "glyphicon-plus-sign";
var PULL_RIGHT = "pull-right";
```

Comment: Oh, big thanks! I just missed it, i had a hard day at work :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var ICON_PLUS_CLASS = "glyphicon-plus-sign";
var PULL_RIGHT = "pull-right";
var $icon = $('<span class="glyphicon medium-icon"></span>').addClass(ICON_PLUS_CLASS).addClass(PULL_RIGHT);
```